# Can't count words from richtextbox to label?

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox, word-count

I'm not sure what's wrong here, but i'm trying to count words in a richtext box, and display that with a label.

I put a richtextbox in a tab control so I can have a tabbed text box. Which seems to make this a lot harder then it should

also this isn't the whole program, I took the parts relating to the richtextbox and word counter

Any help is appreciated :)

```
    public RichTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TabPage tp = new TabPage("Document");
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
        WordCount();
    }

    public RichTextBox RTTB()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = null;
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
        if (tp != null)
        {
            rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }
        return rtb;
    }

    private void WordCount()
    {
        MatchCollection wordColl = Regex.Matches(RTTB().Text, @"[\W]+");
        label2.Text = wordColl.Count.ToString();   
    }
```

Comment: You already dropped a RTB on the tab, so what name does that RTB have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just wire up the `TextChanged` event of the RichTextBox, and count the words there:

```
rtb.TextChanged += rtb_TextChanged;
```

Then count the words (using Giorgio Minardi's regex):

```
private void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  label2.Text = Regex.Matches(((RichTextBox)sender).Text, @"[\S]+").Count.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the actual issue ? 
Here's a simple routine to count words:

```
[Test]
public void CountWords()
{
    const string sample = "How you doing today ?";
    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(sample, @"[\S]+");
    var numberOfWords = collection.Count;
    //numberOfWords is 5
    Assert.IsTrue(numberOfWords == 5);
}
```